# Overwriting sqlite database - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have created a model for an app. I'm trying to overwrite the existing database (blank) with another that has some information. When I look into the database, there are several items. However when I try to load those in a page I get an error saying - there are pending migrations, run db:migrate. After doing that the entire database is wiped out and replace by a blank database. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: 2 questions how are you loading data into db and are you sure you are only running `rake db:migrate` as it sounds like you are dropping it. also are table names and columns the same in db you are importing and your schema file

Comment: i'm actually replacing the blank development sqlite3 file with the one that has data in it. When I run rake db:migrate, I get the migrations pending error. So tht's why I tried dropping the database.

Comment: check that names, credentials and schema matches